# If hourly worker refuses to finish task off the clock, can boss reduce hours?

Tags: united-states, law, hourly

Hourly employee didn't finish work during shift, employer asks you to do it off clock, you refuse, can they retaliate by not giving more paid opportunities?

Comment: They certainly _can_.

Comment: @jkj welcome to The Workplace. In which state are you located? On at-will states I would not be shocked to know this was not rare

Comment: "Surprise" off clocks can be counter-attacked  by "surprise" off duty tasks like "Sorry boss but promised my sister to pick up my nephew at daycare. but keep counting on me please!

Answer (score 4):

> can they retaliate by not giving more paid opportunities?

It's not retaliation, it's necessity, they need the work done and will find someone who can do it. Either the employee is not competent and therefore cannot complete in the designated timeframe. Or the tasks are not being calculated properly.

Having said that, an expectation of working off the clock for an hourly employee is a red flag that your employer has issues, they're not paying you by the task, they're paying you by the hour, and should compensate you for the entirety of your time.

Comment: If the employer needed the work done they would not have asked OP to finish it off clock. Trying to screw over the employee and getting work for free was more important to them then getting the job done.

Comment: @quarague depends how you look at it.

Answer (score 4):

People saying it depends if you are in an at-will/union state don't know US labor laws that well. That being said, exercising your rights under the FLSA does have a cost.

Under the FLSA as an hourly employee you are legally required to be paid for hours that you work, and you are legally required to be paid 1.5 x time for hours that you work past 40 in a week. If your employer doesn't pay you there is both a monetary and criminal cost... There are rather steep penalties for your employer if they don't obey the law, I think the minimum fine is around $4k. And you as the injured party get compensation as well... And you will be able to sue for wrongful termination after the fact (when your employer inevitably fires you for reporting them. Employers who don't follow FLSA tend to retaliate when reported... its a fact of life).

That being said, you will need proof. For example video evidence of you working past hours after you officially clocked out... Or a voice recording... or a text.

My recommendation. Do the time and then talk to your local labor board. Or you can say no... but then you are likley to be fired and/or discriminated against without you having evidence that the employer is doing it in retaliation to them trying to make you work without pay... Evidence is important. He who makes documentation of wrong doing wins.

Yes you will need to find a new job if you follow my suggestion of going to the labor board, but lets be honest do you really want to work for an employer who tried to steal your labor? If you have a pulse and can show up on time there are enough hourly jobs similar to the one that you are currently at in your area that you can get a job the week you are fired. finding work in the US isn't that hard.

Answer (score 2):

The US is (in)famous for having basically zero protections from employers acting like egoistic little kings, as long as they are mean to everyone equally. But there might be an edge case here:

Working unpaid is effectively decreasing your hourly pay. If you only get another 6 hours shift if you work one hour unpaid, you have to divide the money of the shift by seven, not 6, to find out your hourly wage. If that is below the legal minimum wage in your juristiction, you should have a case.

Comment: If you aren't a US citizen.. and don't know US labor laws... you shouldn't really speak with authority. The FLSA exists, and it working off the clock is no bueno to it. infact working overtime and not recieving 1.5x pay does not dice with it.... As long as you can prove it.

Comment: I have no idea what my citizenship has to do with it. Feel free to write your own answer, there is plenty of room on the internet, it has scrollbars. If it's better, it should come out on top, that is how SE is built.

Comment: Best on your comments you don't know US labor laws, yeah they aren't Germany. But they aren't as bad as you think. The US has a lot of protections for employees against employers acting like egoistic little kings.... Its just that very few employees know that those protections exist, because the public school system is not good. The protections exist. The average person just doesn't use them. I guess there is an argument that an unexercised right doesn't exist...

Comment: I'm not sure it really matters if your average hourly wage drops below minimum wage or not. Either the "off the clock" hours are entirely unpaid, or your wage for the hours you already worked is being reduced. It's either unpaid labor or a retroactive pay cut, both of which are illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing an employee's hours because they refuse to work for free is possibly illegal. On the other hand, reducing their hours because they've shown themselves to be unreliable or incapable of finishing the work isn't. It's unclear which it is here, but the employer has likely made things more complicated for themselves by asking for free work.

If you are a non-exempt employee, you must be paid for each hour you work. An employer cannot choose to not pay you for hours worked, or ask you to work "off the clock" without tracking your hours and paying at least minimum wage. The FLSA also prohibits retaliation against employees who exercise their rights - reducing the hours or firing someone because they exercised their FLSA right to be paid for each hour worked is illegal.

That said, most employment contracts are "at will" meaning there is very wide latitude for either side to terminate an employment contract for almost any reason or no reason at all. The employer could certainly fire an employee because they don't finish their work in a timely manner. But they couldn't fire someone for demanding to be paid.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, unless your contract says otherwise and/or you have a good union willing to defend you, they can certainly decide to favor other employees.

And in much of the US, "at-will employment" says they can fire you outright if they want to.

Whether *your* employer will do either, we can't tell you.

Flatly refusing certainly won't win you points for being either efficient or helpful. You might be better advised to try something like "gee, most days I'd be glad to, but I have a commitment right after work today." Be prepared to be questioned about what kind of commitment, and to be asked to work harder to catch up. And you probably can't get away with using this excuse very often.

If it is just a short time, you might want to just work it rather than fight it, even though you shouldn't have to.

Or you might want to have a talk with the boss about getting paid for the additional time, or getting compensating time off on another day when you aren't behind schedule. Or you might want to work with the boss to understand how much work can be completed in a day and set expectations appropriately. But it's easier to have those conversations when you aren't already running late.

Answer (score 1):

> can they retaliate by not giving more paid opportunities?

Unless your contract states otherwise, you are not guaranteed "more paid opportunities".

I'm sure your employer would never use the word "retaliate", but they can give hours to others if they wish.